# Delete cookie in ajax

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using a SSO to log in and out of several sites. When I log out a site, I redirect to the SSO which calls in ajax all of the sites I'm logged in and tell them to destroy a specific cookie.

All of my curent sites use PHP 7.2 or 7.3. I'm making a new website in PHP 8.0 and it won't delete the cookies. It doesn't even access them. The only cookie it has access to is PHPSESSID. But on this site I've 3 cookies : PHPSESSID, XSRF-TOKEN and MY_APP_SESSION. And when I look on my navigator pluging cookie manager I do have the 3 cookies for this site. So it means in ajax it doesn't have access to all the cookies. It actes like if it was a different site.

I tried to use PHP 7.4, it does the same. And I can't test in PHP 7.3 as my dependencies require PHP 7.4 or more.

Is this a protection from PHP that arrives with PHP 7.4 ?
Would you have any tips to help me solve this issue ?

Comment: _But when I look on my cookie manager I do have other cookies for this site_ Other cookies? Other than what?? Do you mean the login cookie is gone but the others are not???? You are really not making yourself clear here

Comment: I have 3 cookies for the site PHPSESSID, XSRF-TOKEN and MY_APP_SESSION. When I dump the cookies in my ajax call, only one shows : PHPSESSID.

Comment: The cookie manager is a plugin from my navigator.

Comment: Check the configuration of the Cookie in your Browser (SameSite-Policy etc).

Comment: For the 2 cookies I don't see, the same-site restriction is "lax". For the PHPSESSID it's "no restriction". So it probable comes from there. I'll see how to change that. Thanks !

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank !